# Coordinate transformation using affine method

Tags: python, numpy, transform

I am trying to convert coordinates from one system to another using the affine transfomation method on python. the code seems to be running but the output is looking strange, here is my code:

```py
    import json
    import math
    import numpy as np
    labels = open('labels3.txt')
    read_ready = labels.read()
    JSONfile = json.loads(read_ready)
    
    #input_system should be the ground plane(georefrenced) images
    #notes on this set of coordinates, assuming that the points arent rotated, may introduce the rotation in @ the very end 
    input_sys = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,23133,0],[35093,23133,0],[35093,0,0]])
    
    #output system should be the slant range coords, these arent too special should be pretty straightforward
    output_sys = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,16384,0],[16384,16384,0],[16384,0,0]])
    
    #now find which point should be transformed
    p = np.array([7954,9338,0])
    
    #finding the transformation 
    l = len(input_sys)
    entry = lambda r,d: np.linalg.det(np.delete(np.vstack([r,input_sys.T,np.ones(l)]),d,axis = 0))
    M = np.array([[(-1)**i * entry(R,i) for R in output_sys.T] for i in range(l+1)])
    
    
    A,t = np.hsplit(M[1:].T/(-M[0])[:,None], [l-1])
    t = np.transpose(t)[0]
    
    #output transform
    print("Affine transformation matrix:\n", A)
    
    print("Affine transformation translation vector:\n", t)
    
    #print("Testing:")
    #for p,P in zip(np.array(input_sys), np.array(output_sys)):
        #image_p = np.dot(A,p)+t
        #result ="[OK]" if np.allclose(image_p,P) else"[ERROR]"
        #print(p, " mapped to: ", image_p, " ; expected: ", P, result)
    #print('Calculation:')
    P = np.dot(A,p)+t
    print(p,'mapped to:', P)
```

the output for the matrix M is a zero matrix which is not correct , can someone help me find a way to get a nonzero matrix out for M?

Comment: what are you doing with that lambda?  the matrix M is the matrix that goes from input to output like output = M .dot input ?

Comment: the labda function is used to create the determinants required to calculate the the affince transform

Comment: but if the affine transform is the one I say you could use `M =output.dot(np.linalg.pinv(input)` as the pseudo inverse used to solve the problem

Comment: ah i see, im farily new to this kind of coding, could you elaborate on your response some more?